# Raspberry pi setting up static IP - address changes but no internet

Tags: static-ip

i have used "sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf" and added static address,
after reboot the raspberry pi shows static address in ifconfig and i can also access it using putty, but it is not able to connect to the internet.
i have checked the router and this device does not show up.
I am sure there is nothing wrong with the router or cable as i was able to access internet before setting the static ip address.

ifconfig before setting static ip[image: ifconfig]

lines i have typed..

```
"interfaces eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.150
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1"
```

Comment: "no internet" is SUCH a vague expression. What's the output of `traceroute -n 23.100.122.175` **and** `ping google.com`

Comment: had the same problem. wrote 'domain_name_server' instead of 'domain_name_servers'. typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided sufficient information to give a definitive answer. You should post what `ifconfig` shows BEFORE attempting to set static (or get this form another computer).

There is at least one obvious error; an incomplete CIDR address. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Address should be

```
static ip_address=192.168.1.150/24
```

The comment about DNS is probably wrong. You may want to use Google's DNS, but you would be far better to use that provided by your ISP. In many cases what you had is correct as the router handles this.

To discover what DNS is in use run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and note the `nameserver`

PS WHY do you want to set a static IP address?

Comment: i have added ifconfig info before setting static ip pls check

Comment: i am building a cluster of raspberry pi, have to use MPI, so setting a static ip will avoid lot of confusion

Comment: When do ISPs run dns servers on local IP addresses? I've never seen that happen in the consumer world before?

Comment: @MohammadAli They don't. You need to learn more about routers before offering advice to others. In general the router knows the DNS (from the ISP) and routes requests from clients.

Comment: I've never really seen that happen too often, I guess it varies as to where on the world you are as ISPs where I live never offer free dns services, but I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using an incorrect dns please change the line below to reflect upon a valid dns service.

```
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

An example of a valid fans would be  googles free public fans located at `8.8.8.8`, so to use googles fans service you would change that line to the following:

```
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

Comment: i have edited the dhcpcd.conf to the dns you have specified

Comment: but no effect. i still did not get internet. i am sorry this is dumb but i dont know how dns works

Comment: What is your output when you ping a site such as Google. Com using the following command `ping google.com`